# passing multiple parameters via Django's {% url %} template tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a code:

.html code:

```
<a href="{% url 'someurl' %}?query1=param1&?query2=param2">
```

views.py code:

```
query1 = request.GET.get('query1','') or None
query2 = request.GET.get('query2','') or None
```

I can't get the query2 value. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra `?`. There should only be one and different query parameters would be separated by an `&`:

```
<a href="{% url 'someurl' %}?query1=param1&query2=param2">
```

Also that `or None` is unneeded. Change your python code to:

```
query1 = request.GET.get('query1')
query2 = request.GET.get('query2')
```

The `.get` method would either return the value of the provided key or `None`. If you also provide a default like you did it would return the default (instead of `None`) if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! Have a great day.